# Data visualisation tool based on games played by user

Tags: android, google-play-services, visualization

I am a complete beginner in android development and for self-learning purposes thinking of creating a visualisation tool where different progress graphs of user's high score vs time or latest scores among all games will be displayed. The game in observation can be any game selected by user from the list of all games played by him till date. I just want to know is this possible to do in google play games API? If yes how can I do so? i.e. displaying high score or latest score from any game played by him till date?

Comment: I have not found a way in Android to find out what games the player has interacted with. It sounds like the kind of data mining excercise that would not be allowed by the platform. I do not know for sure you can't, but I would be surprised if you could.

Comment: @Almo I was reading about the 'Game' class in API. What it gives access to exactly?